# not able to install fable package (error: is not available (for R version 3.4.2)

Tags: r, package, installation, forecast, fable-r

Hi anyone could give some suggestion?
I am trying to install fable package but when I got the error message: 
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘fable’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)

any solution??
Thank you!

Comment: At first I thought this was an issue of your R version being too old, which is the typical reason for that error. However, this is an issue where `fable` is not yet on CRAN. To install it, try `devtools::install_github("tidyverts/fable")` (see its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable))

Comment: This makes this a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/), though I can't vote to close right now. Specifically, this issue is addressed in point 8 of [the top answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/8386140)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 2):

As the `fable` package located at GitHub repositary you should use `devtools` package `install_github`. Please see the code below:

```
installed.packages("devtools")
install.packages("tsibble")
library(devtools)
install_github("tidyverts/fable")
library(fable)
```